# Best way to delete submitted data in Sprout Forms?

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

There are a few hundred form entries and manually going into each one and deleting sounds like far too much work!

Guess i could delete each form (there are 5) which would delete each form submisson. Then recreate the form again. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the checkbox at the top to select all of them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Daryl, turns out i'm using an older version of the plugin.